# Sublime - Activate/Deactivate - Auto Save on Modified -- Plugin

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am already aware of the user-defined ignored packages setting in SublimeText2.  Is there a way to modify this plugin -- e.g., with a keymap assignment -- to activate or deactivate this useful autosave feature?  Perhaps chaining a plugin to the package control enable / disable feature, and assigning a keymap?

Here is the link to where I first discovered this plugin:  [Is there a way to autosave on each keystroke in sublime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277166/is-there-a-way-to-autosave-on-each-keystroke-in-sublime/15279948#15279948)

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class SaveOnModifiedListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
def on_modified(self, view):
    view.run_command("save")
```

Comment: Here is a simple solution -- create a folder within packages and add the plugin; then, create a user-defined keymap for Package Control settings:

    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+super+d"], "command": "disable_package" },
    { "keys": ["f1"], "command": "enable_package" },

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without relying on the package control commands. I can give you the answer, but I know you have been exploring writing plugins, so this might be a good exercise. It's pretty simple. Here are a couple hints though.

In the on modified command, you can check for a setting. You can give it a default value (I would do False) for if the setting does not exist. You can either write a text command to toggle the setting, or simply create a key binding with the `toggle_setting` command. Both will work, though if you write a command you can do something like create a status message so you know if save on modified is active or not. For information on toggle settings, see http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/settings.html.

If you just want the answer though, just let me know and I'll post it.

Comment: Thank you for the hints -- I'd be happy to give it a whirl and report back with a potential coded solution -- I'll work on it a little each day as time permits.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Go to Preferences -> Settings
2. Add the following line:

   "save_on_focus_lost": true,

It would not automatically save the current file, however it would when you change the focus on other windows, Alt + Tab to terminal for example.