# Sublime Text plugin installing and using?

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I am new to Sublime Text as well as web developing. I was looking for something that can save the file when any changes are made to it. I came across to
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277166/is-there-a-way-to-autosave-on-each-keystroke-in-sublime/15279948#15279948). It seems promising. But the problem is I don't know how to install this and use this. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652758/install-plugins-to-sublimetext-2). But it didn't helped. So can someone tell me how to

- Create this plugin
- Install this plugin
- Use this plugin

Step by step help would be really nice if possible.
Or If someone can point me to another editor with this functionality I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure you really want to do this, here's how:

1. Select `File -> New File`, then `View -> Syntax -> Python`.
2. Paste the following:

   ```py
   import sublime, sublime_plugin

   class SaveOnModifiedListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
       def on_modified(self, view):
           view.run_command("save")
   ```
3. Select `File -> Save As...` and save as `Packages/User/save_on_modified.py`. The `Packages` directory is either in `%APPDATA%/Roaming/Sublime Text 2` on Windows, `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2` on OSX, or `~/.config/sublime-text-2` on Linux. You can find this directory by selecting `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`. On OSX the `Preferences` menu is a sub-menu of `Sublime Text 2`, on other OSes it's its own menu next to all the others. When you select `Save As...` you may already be in the `User` directory (I was on my machine).
4. Restart Sublime, just for fun. If you're on OSX, make sure you quit by using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>, not just closing the window by clicking on the red button.
5. You now should be good to go. This will now save every file, of any type, after every single modification. Again, make sure you really want to do this.
6. If at some point you decide you don't want to do this anymore, just delete `save_on_modified.py` or move it to a directory **outside of** the `Packages` hierarchy.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Working like a charm. I wanted this for a live preview of my code in the browser, just like JSBIN or others. And by the way I am using Windows.